# Random SetConsoleTitle name

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-c++, console

Looking how to make title random every time its loaded

```
SetConsoleTitle("Injector-BETA");
hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~(WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX));
```

Comment: Anyone help me?

Comment: Did you get this figured out, I can maybe help with this. Please don't forget about my SuperUser answer from long ago you told me was working here: https://superuser.com/questions/1030214/need-assistance-with-an-existing-batch-file and see the note I left you there with a link. Once you follow up on that, I think I can help easily with this.

Comment: You should be able to toggle between SO and SU easily with the same login in case that's the issue.